# Deployment Error - Flow Must Have a Start Item

Tags: deployment, flow, visual-flows

I am trying to deploy a flow that simply invokes Apex. It works as expected during functional testing. However, when I attempt to deploy it with Eclipse, I get the below error.

```
Deploy Results:
File Name: flows/MyFlow.flow
Full Name: MyFlow
Action: NO ACTION
Result: FAILED
Problem: The flow must have a start item.
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi Adrian, How you are invoking flow during functional testing ? did u checked this - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h0OsAAI

Comment: When you created the flow, did you assign a block as the 'Start' (A Green + will appear in the block defined as a starting block. If you don't tell the flow where to start, it can't run.

Comment: Yep, we have invoked it during functional testing, and we did assign a start block.